# Alternatives to copying the folder created with venv for many machines to use the environment

Tags: python, python-venv

I have around 30 machines and I plan to use them all to run a distributed training python script.They all have the same username, in case this helps. I am on Windows and need to use the GPU in case this helps too. They all have the same python version and software installations necessary but I would need them to have the same version modules installed (pandas, matplotlib, etc).

My approach: I initially used one machine to run `python -m venv myenv` and then did `pip install -r requirements.txt`. I put the folder in a network drive and had all machine change directory to that network drive. Since they all have the same username I though it would be ok. It worked on a couple of them but not all of them. The alternative solution would be to have all machines run the command `python -m venv myenv` `pip install -r requirements.txt` but wouldn't this not be ideal? What if I have to add a module? Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: I am hoping for an alternative solution to Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30 machines is quite a lot of machines to manage by hand. Presumably you have SSH access to them and are thinking of some solution for batch-deploying the application to all of them.

This sounds like a perfect use case for [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/basic_concepts.html). If you're not familiar with, I recommend to check it out and investigate how well it works with Windows hosts (personally I have only used it with Linux machines; [FAQ for Windows](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_faq.html)). It has a bit of a learning curve, but as soon as you have prepared a working playbook for deploying the application to 1 machine, you can just extend the list of hosts and deploy the exact same thing to all 30.

Basically I would create a playbook to make the machines each create a local virtual environment with dependencies, but I would manage them from a single node.

Sample playbook:

```yaml
---

- name: Do stuff
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: all
  vars:
    virtual_environment: "/home/pi/test_env"

  tasks:
    - name: Install low-level dependencies
      become: true
      apt:
        name: libatlas-base-dev
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Install pip dependencies
      pip:
        name:
          - pandas
          - matplotlib
          - numpy
        virtualenv: "{{ virtual_environment }}"
        virtualenv_command: python3 -m venv

    - name: Execute some script
      command:
        cmd: |
          {{ virtual_environment }}/bin/python -c '
          import pandas as pd
          print("Pandas is installed under:", pd.__file__)
          '
      register: script

    - name: Print the output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ script.stdout }}"
```

Sample inventory:

```
192.168.0.24
```

Output:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml

PLAY [Do stuff] **************************************************************************

TASK [Install low-level dependencies] ****************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.24]

TASK [Install pip dependencies] **********************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.24]

TASK [Execute some script] ***************************************************************
changed: [192.168.0.24]

TASK [Print the output] ******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.24] => {
    "msg": "Pandas is installed under: /home/pi/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************
192.168.0.24               : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Note how for most tasks this run resulted in "ok" rather than "changed" - this is because I had already run this playbook before and this time Ansible noticed that the packages were already installed so there's no need to do it over again. Most Ansible modules are set up in this way which makes it efficient. Refer to the (pretty good!) docs to figure out what parameters are available for each module (in the above example, modules are: `apt`, `pip`, `command`, `debug`).

Comment: Yes, your last sentence is what I would be looking for. Do you have a rough template of what this would imply before I dig deep into this? Especially since you say it has a learning curve. How does the node work with the remotes? Through SSH?

Comment: From the [Windows FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_faq.html) it looks like you'd have to set up WSL on the control node as Ansible can't run directly on Windows. Apart from that, on Linux it requires Python to be present, which it normally already is. On Windows, it sounds from the FAQ like it just needs PowerShell, which should also already be there. It doesn't require installing any agent - it just uses SSH (Linux) or PowerShell (Windows) to connect to the remote machines and execute commands there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a conda environment and the export it:

`conda-env export -n myenvnaame > myenvfile.yml`

and then import on the other machines:

`conda-env create -n venv -f=myenvfile.yml`

or in alternative you could use docker and share the image on all the machines

Comment: Wouldn't that be pretty much the same thing? What if I have to add one module? I'll be doing that on all machines? I believe I cannot use Docker because I am on windows and need the GPU -- as of today it looks like Nvidia-docker for gpu use is only for Linux unless you upgrade to their preview built which I cannot

Comment: ok so an alternative would be poetry https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry. With poetry you just have a toml file with the dependencies and if you share the code on the machines you could write a script that runs a git pull + poetry install periodically or triggered by something else

Answer (score 1):

Although this is slightly outside the realm of pure-python, creating a docker container for the execution, completing a setup with build instructions, would allow complete isolation of that venv from its surrounding machine setup.

Docker allows for multiple instances running on the same box to share the same definitions, so if you have a situation where you're running 5 copies of the same code, it can re-use the same memory IIRC for the shared in-mem code runtimes.  I've read this, haven't tried the memory spec though.

Comment: Yeah I should have added that in my question -- per the comment I left below I am not looking into docker because of my need to use the GPU.